# How do I negate a test with regular expressions in a bash script?

Tags: regex, bash, conditional-statements, negate

Using GNU bash (version 4.0.35(1)-release (x86_64-suse-linux-gnu), I would like to negate a test with Regular Expressions. For example, I would like to conditionally add a path to the PATH variable, if the path is not already there, as in:

```
TEMP=/mnt/silo/bin
if [[ ${PATH} =~ ${TEMP} ]] ; then PATH=$PATH; else PATH=$PATH:$TEMP; fi
TEMP=/mnt/silo/Scripts:
if [[ ${PATH} =~ ${TEMP} ]] ; then PATH=$PATH; else PATH=$PATH:$TEMP; fi
TEMP=/mnt/silo/local/bin
if [[ ${PATH} =~ ${TEMP} ]] ; then PATH=$PATH; else PATH=$PATH:$TEMP; fi
export PATH
```

I'm sure there are a million ways to do this, but what I would like to know is if the conditional can be negated somehow, as in (the erroneous):

```
TEMP=/mnt/silo/bin
if ![[ ${PATH} =~ ${TEMP} ]] ; then PATH=$PATH:$TEMP; fi
TEMP=/mnt/silo/Scripts:
if ![[ ${PATH} =~ ${TEMP} ]] ; then PATH=$PATH:$TEMP; fi
TEMP=/mnt/silo/local/bin
if ![[ ${PATH} =~ ${TEMP} ]] ; then PATH=$PATH:$TEMP; fi
export PATH
```

Answer (score 325, accepted):

You had it right, just put a space between the `!` and the `[[` like `if ! [[`

Comment: Oye vey! Just when I safely sidestep the intergalactic special character madness of perl, I find myself lost in bash space (placement)! (I feel fear squeezing my gut like a python.) Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure that it's always before `[[` and not inside, like `if [[ ! "$value" =~ $regex ]];`? For example, Sublime Text highlights it weirdly if outside: https://i.imgur.com/AQWuFtf.png

Comment: intelliJ gives this warning; You are missing a required space after the !.
See [SC1035](https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck/wiki/SC1035).

Comment: @RichardTylerMiles this answer *does* have the space after the '!'.  You can also put the '!' inside the double-brackets, I just prefer it outside.

Answer (score 193):

You can also put the exclamation point inside the brackets:

```
if [[ ! $PATH =~ $temp ]]
```

but you should anchor your pattern to reduce false positives:

```
temp=/mnt/silo/bin
pattern="(^|:)$temp(:|$)"
if [[ ! $PATH =~ $pattern ]]
```

which looks for a match at the beginning or end with a colon before or after it (or both). I recommend using lowercase or mixed case variable names as a habit to reduce the chance of name collisions with shell variables.

Comment: Ah, thanks for the reminder about anchoring. The idea of using lowercase or mixed variable names is confusing to a bash beginner, since the advice I have seen so far is to use uppercase. I understand the point you are making, but I have not seen enough bash scripting examples to feel comfortable deviating from (my understanding of) the cookbook.

Comment: @anyoneis trust us on this one. Use of user-defined uppercase variables should be avoided.  All variables in bash are expanded with `$` so there is no reason to uppercase them to make them stand out.

Comment: I find `if [[ ! $foo =~ bar ]]` safer than `if ! [[ $foo =~ bar ]]`, because it makes easier to introduce more conditions to the `if`

Answer (score 28):

the safest way is to put the ! for the regex negation within the `[[ ]]` like this:

```
if [[ ! ${STR} =~ YOUR_REGEX ]]; then
```

otherwise it might fail on certain systems.

Answer (score 11):

Yes you can negate the test as [SiegeX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4542732/how-do-i-negate-a-test-with-regular-expressions-in-a-bash-script/4542761#4542761) has already pointed out.

However you shouldn't use regular expressions for this - it can fail if your path contains special characters. Try this instead:

```
[[ ":$PATH:" != *":$1:"* ]]
```

[(Source)](https://superuser.com/questions/39751/add-directory-to-path-if-its-not-already-there/39995#39995)

Comment: Another reason to use this form it that it won't accidentally match substrings (e.g. fail to add "/bin" to the path because "/usr/bin" is already there).

Comment: It took me a while to understand how the colons on the left gave me the anchoring I wanted. the idea of reducing the pattern by adding material to the string to be searched is worth remembering. I don't understand why special characters in the path would disrupt the regex solution but not the bash pattern solution. Can you give me an example?

Comment: I don't think this will work reliably in all cases. Regex matching in superior IMHO

Answer (score 7):

I like to simplify the code without using conditional operators in such cases:

```
TEMP=/mnt/silo/bin
[[ ${PATH} =~ ${TEMP} ]] || PATH=$PATH:$TEMP
```