# How do I negate two logic tests with regular expressions in a bash script?

Tags: regex, bash, if-statement

In bash, we would like to do the following logic: if the variable `"$SLACK"` is `TRUE` and `${OUTPUT}` is not equal to `"mysql: [Warning] Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure"`, call the `slack_it` function.

I have tried more than a dozen solutions provided from the posts here [How do I negate a test with regular expressions in a bash script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4542732/how-do-i-negate-a-test-with-regular-expressions-in-a-bash-script), [Check if a string matches a regex in Bash script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21112707/check-if-a-string-matches-a-regex-in-bash-script), but none of them work. Could any guru enlighten?

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ "$SLACK" == "TRUE" ]
   then
        if ! [[ ${OUTPUT} =~ "*mysql: [Warning] Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure*" ]]
            then
                slack_it
        fi
  fi
```

Comment: I am curious why you are set on using a regular expression. It sounds like you got it to work without a regular expression. Why complicate things? Or is this a mind exercise?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The stars need to be outside the quotes.

Also, the `=~` operator is for regex, `==` for globs.

So:

```
if ! [[ ${OUTPUT} == *"mysql: [Warning] Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure"* ]]; then
    slack_it
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

Your issue seems to be related to the leading and trailing `*`.  Try:

```
if ! [[ ${OUTPUT} =~ "mysql: [Warning] Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure" ]]; then
  slack_it
fi
```

Comment: You also [can't use quotes when matching regular expressions in Bash](http://stackoverflow.com/q/218156/1426891), or it'll force string matching. Saving the regex to a variable seems to be the workaround of choice.